# using visual studio IDE using Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, mono, monodevelop

I've been checking around for working with VS IDE instaed of Mono's, I understood that I have to download vsprj2me, something like that, but couldn't find any activate download for that.
Is it true that I have to download it? And if so, can anybody supply me a link for a download?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default MonoDroid installer performs necessary configurations automatically. You should simply provide a path to the Android SDK: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows#Configuring_Visual_Studio

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not see any Mono for android in the options, here I took an SS of my C# visual studio (2010) IDE: http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8576/90090493.png What am I missing?

Comment: What version do you use? Please note that Express editions doesn't support third party add-ins.

Comment: Oh really? I am using Express edition.. uh dammit.. Other editions aren't free right?

Comment: That's the point to make it free. Check for used boxes on Ebay. You may find a good price there.

Comment: holy crap.. it costs more than 1000$, I'm giving up on this, thank you.