# Xamarin F# projects in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, f#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I installed the f# extensions for Xamarin studio, to create monodroid f# projects.
However, this project won't open in Visual Studio.
Are there f# project templates available for visual studio?

Comment: Visual studio definitely has F# project templates, but at least the default ones probably won't work with monodroid.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking specifically about Xamarin templates. Opening such an F# Xamarin project, VS says this project type is not supported.

Comment: Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108581/android-applications-using-monodroid or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180661/using-visual-studio-ide-using-mono-for-android help? (they are C# questions but normally the C# stuff will work for F#)

Comment: No, the problem is that the F# support only gets installed through a Xamarin studio addon, which won't integrate with VS.

Comment: I don't like your chances of this working - this page http://fsharp.org/use/android/ seems to imply by omission that what you want is not possible.

Comment: This has changed - the current versions of Xamarin (Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio + Xamarin support) definitely include F#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no such templates available at this time. I can't cite you an online source but I asked this exact question of Miguel De Icaza at the Progressive F# Tutorials in NYC and he said there were not.

Comment: Has anyone heard any updates on this, or know where any progress is being tracked?